# How to maintain a connection to a server?

Tags: c++, rest, http, curl

I'm just starting with HTTP and I need to connect to a server.I found this helpful [code](https://github.com/mrtazz/restclient-cpp) .So when I tried this :

```
RestClient::response r = RestClient::get("http://localhost:8080/services/login?username=admin&password=changemenow");
NSLog(@"%s",r.body.c_str());
RestClient::response rp = RestClient::get("http://localhost:8080/services/logout");
NSLog(@"%s",rp.body.c_str());
```

For the first request I get :

```
{
  "loginSuccess" : true,
  "sessionId" : "1xmtxh729fepulbfyt8qgf0an",
  "serverVersion" : "5.2.2.6"
}
```

whereas for the second I get :

```
{
  "errorcode" : 401,
  "message" : "Not logged in"
}
```

What should I do to maintain the connection?

Comment: You probably need to send the session ID to the server (so it knows which session you're talking about). This depends on the server's API though, so it depends on how the server works.

Comment: For most real-life servers, you'll need to send the cookies from the first response, in the second request. However, I don't know how to do that with this particular library. If it has a thing called "CookieJar" anywhere, then that's probably the easiest way, but it surely must have a way of letting you read cookies from responses, and set them on requests. As Cornstalks says, though, it's entirely up to the web server what (if anything) you're meant to do with that `sessionId`. Which is why server APIs need to be documented.